# Proving the connectedness of symmetric regions

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

If $G$ is a region (connected open set) that is symmetric with respect to the real axis, then is $G∩H$ also connected? Here $H$ is the upper half plane. It is intuitively clear but I cannot prove it rigorously. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of @Randall: can be used as follows: let $x$, $y$ point in $G\cap H$. Take a path inside $G$ joining $x$ and $y$. Apply the folding map to get a path from $x$ to $y$ situated entirely in $G\cap \bar H$. Raise this path by $\epsilon$ to a path inside $G\cap H$ from $x_{\epsilon}$ to $y_{\epsilon}$. If $\epsilon$ is small enough we have a path from $x$ to $x_{\epsilon}$ and from $y$ to $y_{\epsilon}$ inside $G\cap H$.

Comment: This is a great idea.  I believe you are using facts like (a) an open connected set in the plane is also path connected and (b) a path must intersect the $x$-axis somewhat nicely in order to make the little deformations work.  Is this true?

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, now I see.  You are raising the entire path by a bit to get it off the $x$-axis, which will be fine since we still have open-ness.  RIght?

Comment: Great teamwork, kids. ;o)

Comment: @Randall: The folding map was the secret weapon.  Initially I thought of rounding off some corners of the path ( would definitely work for polygonal path), then found an  escape hatch.

Comment: Need a $\fistbump$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $H$ includes the $x$-axis.

Define a map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by folding the lower half-plane onto the upper.  This is continuous and fixes $H$ (it is a projection).

$G$ is connected and by assumption, $f(G) = G \cap H$.  Hence $G \cap H$ is connected.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question. I intend $H$ not to include the real axis. How can I prove in that case?

Comment: I dunno.  Does my proof still work?

Comment: With my argument you get that $(G \cap H) \cup (G \cap X)$ is connected, where $X$ is the $x$-axis.  You need to throw away $G \cap X$ and retain connectivity.  So, I bet my argument either doesn't work or is too hard to bother with.  There's an easier way.

Comment: Great argument, and still usable.